How to find the unique fields in elasticsearch/opensearch and order by its value(some other field)? (Find set of Distinct values in elasticsearch)
I have an index in my elasticsearch with multiple fields, out of which I want to fetch 2 fields combination (id , name). How to write the query such that i want to order the result(based on whole index and not just the result set) based on name and fetch results by unique id?
In brief, I want to find the equivalent of this SQL:
SELECT DISTINCT id, name FROM abc ORDER BY name desc

Please note, I want the final results sorted on whole index, not just the result set query provides.
What will be the best way to write this query in elasticsearch?

As per my understanding, you want to retrieve unique data based on id field and sort based on name field.
Please find below query which will return desired output.
POST sample_data/_search
{
  "size": 10000, 
  "_source": [
    "id",
    "name"
  ],
  "sort": [
    {
      "name": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "id"
  }
}

Above query will sort all the data in your index and then will return top 10000 documents. If you need more then 10000 result then you need to use search-after functionality of ES.
Another things you need to make sure here is that, id field must be type of keyword.

I doubt if this works, it got me this error
cannot usecollapsein conjunction withsearch_after
`

how many records you want to extract from ES ?

The no of unique values might exceed 10k.

Introduction
Suitable ways to solve your issue are aggregations
Mapping with the name and id fields
PUT /names_ids
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "id": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}

Sample documents
PUT /names_ids/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"name":"John", "id": "a"}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"name":"John", "id": "b"}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"name":"James", "id": "a"}
{"create":{"_id":4}}
{"name":"James", "id": "b"}
{"create":{"_id":5}}
{"name":"Johan", "id": "a"}
{"create":{"_id":6}}
{"name":"Johan", "id": "b"}
{"create":{"_id":7}}
{"name":"Johan", "id": "c"}

The terms Aggregation
The first way is to perform the terms aggregations by name (parent) and id (sibling)
GET /names_ids/_search?filter_path=aggregations.by_name.buckets
{
    "aggs": {
        "by_name": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "name",
                "size": 10000,
                "order": {
                    "_key": "desc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "by_id": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "id",
                        "size": 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "aggregations" : {
        "by_name" : {
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : "John",
                    "doc_count" : 2,
                    "by_id" : {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                        "buckets" : [
                            {
                                "key" : "a",
                                "doc_count" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                "key" : "b",
                                "doc_count" : 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Johan",
                    "doc_count" : 3,
                    "by_id" : {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                        "buckets" : [
                            {
                                "key" : "a",
                                "doc_count" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                "key" : "b",
                                "doc_count" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                "key" : "c",
                                "doc_count" : 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key" : "James",
                    "doc_count" : 2,
                    "by_id" : {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                        "buckets" : [
                            {
                                "key" : "a",
                                "doc_count" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                "key" : "b",
                                "doc_count" : 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

The multi_terms Aggregation
The second way is the multi_terms aggregation by name and id
GET /names_ids/_search?filter_path=aggregations.by_names_ids.buckets
{
    "aggs": {
        "by_names_ids": {
            "multi_terms": {
                "terms": [
                    {
                        "field": "name"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "id"
                    }
                ],
                "order": {
                    "_key": "desc"
                },
                "size": 10000
            }
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "aggregations" : {
        "by_names_ids" : {
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : [
                        "John",
                        "b"
                    ],
                    "key_as_string" : "John|b",
                    "doc_count" : 1
                },
                {
                    "key" : [
                        "John",
                        "a"
                    ],
                    "key_as_string" : "John|a",
                    "doc_count" : 1
                },
                {
                    "key" : [
                        "Johan",
                        "c"
                    ],
                    "key_as_string" : "Johan|c",
                    "doc_count" : 1
                },
                {
                    "key" : [
                        "Johan",
                        "b"
                    ],
                    "key_as_string" : "Johan|b",
                    "doc_count" : 1
                },
                {
                    "key" : [
                        "Johan",
                        "a"
                    ],
                    "key_as_string" : "Johan|a",
                    "doc_count" : 1
                },
                {
                    "key" : [
                        "James",
                        "b"
                    ],
                    "key_as_string" : "James|b",
                    "doc_count" : 1
                },
                {
                    "key" : [
                        "James",
                        "a"
                    ],
                    "key_as_string" : "James|a",
                    "doc_count" : 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

Conclusion
I'm not sure the keys could be sorted on whole index



Doesn't it seems odd to first group by name and then by id? Like shouldn't it be either way around?


I have thought of multi_terms but i think they have a bit slow performance.
https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/aggregations/bucket/multi-terms/



A parent aggregation groups data by name so that it can be sorted later. You could swap the parent and sibling aggregations. Thanks for your comment

I don't think I can swap the the parent-child aggregation because I think the sorting based on sub-aggregation does not work properly.

Why do you think the sorting based on sub-aggregation does not work properly? Just test it

I tried this but it did not work. Here is my query...
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "name.keyword",
            "order": {
              "_key": "asc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



@Umang Kamdar, please, provide expected result of the query in your question

My expected result is as simple as the output of the sample query I mentioned in the question.
SELECT DISTINCT id, name FROM abc ORDER BY name desc
So if there are 200k records, out of which arnd 15k records may be unique(ie unique combination of id,name), then i want to fetch all the 15k records sorted on name.

Did you test my mapping, documents, and query?
